# Use different fields to validate in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am using the ASP.NET identity but I would like to validate the user with different fields instead of using the email (or username) and the password.

In my scenario the user has a keycode instead of the email. That keycode field I know how to add to the `IdentityUser` through the `ApplicationUser` but I found trouble when I need to check if it exists in the database. The `UserManager` has methods to find the user by username and password (or email) but not for the custom properties I added (obviously).

I tried to implement my own `UserManager` but it seemed such a big effort for quite "simple" thing. I just need one extra method.

One solution is using the username as the field to store the keycode. However I don't like the idea very much. It is not very clean, feels like cheating; and I may need that field in the future for its original purpose.

Is a solution with a better a trade-off between complexity and clean solution?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The limitation is in the *IUserStore* (only has Create, Update, Delete, FindById and FindByName(username) methods) that's what the *UserManager* is using to retrive the data from the database. So if you want to extend the *UserManager* with a new function that gives you an user by keycode you also needs to extend the *IUserStore*.

In general I dont like the solution of putting "wrong data" in a property. So, to extend the UserManager and the UserStore regarding your needs, you do like this:

First extend the IUserStore interface

```
public interface IMyUserStore : IUserStore<User>
{
    Task<User> FindByKeyCodeAsync(string keyCode);
}
```

Implement the new interface

```
public class MyUserStore : UserStore<User>, IMyUserStore
{
    public Task<User> FindByKeyCodeAsync(string keyCode)
    {
        return Users.Where(x => x.KeCode == keyCode);
    }
}
```

Extend the UserManager

```
public class MyUserManager : UserManager<User>
{
    private readonly IMyUserStore _store;

    public MyUserManager(IMyUserStore store)
        : base(store)
    {
        _store = store;
    }

    public virtual Task<User> FindByKeyCodeAsync(string keyCode)
    {
        var a = new UserStore<User>();
        return _store.FindByKeyCodeAsync(keyCode);
    }
}
```

And if you want to get a user by any parameter it has you can change the FindByKeyCodeAsync method to:

```
public Task<User> Find(Expression<Func<User, bool>> expression)
{
    return Users.SingleAsync(expression);
}
```